# how to transfer columns of python generated pivot table into new excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pivot, subtotal

I have a pivot table generated using python code:

```
Date                             Grand Total
Name       1/2/2010   2/2/2010
Alice        5          6           11
bob          5          5           10 
Clarke       4          8           12
Dwayne       3          4           7
```

I want the columns 'Name' and 'Grand Total'to be written in new excel sheet.
Can anyone help me on this
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have the code for reproducing the dataframe. Nevertheless, I think I was able to reproduce your example.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alice', 'bob', 'Clarke', 'Dwayne', 'Alice', 'bob', 'Clarke', 'Dwayne', 'Alice'], 'Date': ['1/2/2010','1/2/2010','1/2/2010','1/2/2010','2/2/2010', '2/2/2010','2/2/2010','2/2/2010','2/2/2010'], 'N': [5,5,4,3,5,5,8,4,1]})
 df = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Date', values='N', aggfun='sum')
 df['Grand Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

As it is a pandas dataframe you can simply export to a CSV file by

```
 df['Grand Total'].to_csv('pivot_table.csv')
```

Or to Excel:

```
 df['Grand Total'].to_excel("name_of_the_file.xlsx", sheet_name='DisiredSheetName')
```

You can find existing documentation on [Pandas to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)